# can i dual boot ubuntu and kali linux on a externel hard disk drive? if so how?

Tags: dual-boot, external-hdd

i am currently using linux mint 20 but i want to make it windows 10 and want to dual boot ubuntu and kali linux on my external HDD. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this external HDD connected by USB? You're generally going to have a bad time if your r/w is going to be throttled by your USB bus.  Also, why would you need to install Kali? Kali is a distro for advanced users with a very narrow and specific focus: It's intended to be run from a live session. Apologies for making assumptions, but generally those who are asking how to *install* Kali aren't really sure what they are doing..

Comment: Depends how the drives are mixed.  SSD with a USB 2 external sucks.  Similar drives not so much.  Kali would not be one of my top choices.

Comment: Before proceeding with the install to the external drive, it is best to unplug your internal drive. Install Kali then install Ubuntu last to ensure GRUB is working. After install plug in internal drive, boot Ubuntu and in Terminal run `sudo update-grub` to add everything else to the boot menu.

Comment: I am learning ethical hacking that's why i need Kali, i tried it on virtual machine but it is lagging too much. I don't have a SSD and my external HDD is USB 3.0

Comment: Did the method I show above not work for you? Unplug your internal drive and install Kali on your external drive. If you have problems Google installing Kali with GRUB boot loader, (installing Kali is not an Ask Ubuntu topic). Then install Ubuntu using "Something Else". After install boot Ubuntu to confirm it is working, then boot Kali to confirm it is working. Then plug in the internal drive, boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to the boot loader menu. GRUB should work for booting all three OS as long as the external is set as first HDD.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible.  Install same way as Mint but use the something else option on the installer/s.  Check everything so you make sure to install on proper partition/s.  Should backup all important data.  All OSs should be installed same way, UEFI with GPT partition drive or Legacy bios with MBR drive.  Windows might play nicer if installed first then Ubuntu and kali